# Is there a difference in the working of AND operator in JAVA and C?

Tags: java, c

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class InsertionSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arr = new int[s.nextInt()];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        s.close();
        new RunInsertionSort().insertionSort(arr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}

class RunInsertionSort {
    public void insertionSort(int[] arr) {
        int i, j, temp;
        for (i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            temp = arr[i];
            j = i - 1;
            while ((j >= 0) && (temp < arr[j])) {
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                j--;
            }
            arr[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

If `j>=0` is placed after the condition `temp< arr[j]`, I'm getting the error as

```
5

5 4 3 2 1

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 5

    at RunInsertionSort.insertionSort(InsertionSort.java:22)

    at InsertionSort.main(InsertionSort.java:12)
```

But in C language this doesn't happen either I write `j>=0 && temp < arr[i]` or `temp<arr[i] && j>=0`.

1st Image
[Image of Error when j>=0 is placed after temp<arr[j]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY7q8.png)

2nd Image [Image when j>=0 is placed before temp<arr[j]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AcFb.png)

Comment: The answer is **no**

Comment: Also, works without an error for me `5 5 4 3 2 1
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: C doesn't do index bounds checks. It happily accesses a nonsensical index -1 of an array even though the array has only allowed indexes 0 to some value.

Comment: The difference is not in how `&&` works, but in how programming errors are treated. Java checks for invalid array accesses and raises an exception. C lets you stomp happily into invalid terrain and calls it "undefined behaviour", something the programmer has to avoid.

Comment: @ThomasKläger But how does placing the same condition before or after another condition result in error. && operator should check both the conditions if the first one is true.

Comment: If you put the access first, you cannot be sure that you have a valid index. It is the other way round: You must rely on the fact that the second condition isn't checked when the first one is false. That way, you will never make an invalid access if your index is invalid. The pattern goes `(precondition_for_test && actual_test)`.

Comment: "&& operator should check both the conditions if the first one is true" - correct, but if j is -1 then the condition `j >= 0` is false. If the complete condition is `(j >= 0) && (temp < arr[j])` then its `false && something` and that something is never evaluated. If the complete condition is `((temp < arr[j]) && (j >= 0))` then the array access is evaluated first and trying to access an array at index -1 throws the exception.

Comment: @ThomasKläger @M Oehm thankyou for clearing the doubt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Its called shortcircuit.

The order can affect your condition because if any of the conditions from left to right fails, it will mark the complete condition as false and doesn't evaluate any more conditions.

```
while ((j >= 0) && (temp < arr[j]))
```

So if `j >= 0` is false, it will not evaluate `temp < arr[j]`

but if you interchange first it will evaluate `temp < arr[j]` where `arr[j]` can produce an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Java.

You can read more about [shortCircuit](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/short-circuit-logical-operators-in-java-with-examples/).

In C, it may not give an exception; rather it may give you a garbage value.